# Setting Image Resource

Tags: android, image, drawable

I'm setting an Image Resource for an ImageView. Depending on the condition, the ImageView will display an specific image.

I'm using this code:

```
exerciseImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.treadmill);
```

At the first two condition(ifs), this line doesn't show any error. While the next Ifs, errors occur. I can guarantee that my images are at my, drawable folder. Because the first to ifs doesn't show any error. When I try to use the intellisense, the desired images doesn't show up. Some are there but most of them are not. I really don't know what the problem is because all images are at my drawablefolder. Any ideas?

I'm getting and error. "Cannot be resolved or is not a field"

[image]

Comment: once build and clean the project

Comment: If cleaning and building doesn't work, post the if statements you're talking about.

Comment: Will the cleaning affect the project? I've done that before and after cleaning, it causes me a lot of errors. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be the `R.java` file has not been generated in your project.

Check if you have error in any of your xml files and next check if your images are having valid names.

and later build and clean the project. If the problem still exists try checking if you have any import statement with something like `import android.R;` delete it and again build and clean the project

Comment: See my updated post, there are errors in my xml file, regarding the R.java, how should I know if it was generated or not?

Comment: uppercase is not allowed for resource names.. only lowercase(a-z), 0-9, .(dot) and _ are valid. Change the names of the images which are voilating the rule of naming conventions

Comment: Thanks! That did it. I didn't know that one wrong naming conventions will affect my whole resources. :)